# CLI cURL works flawlessly, Apache with mod_php cannot resolve host, how to fix?

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, php, arch-linux

Setup:

- cURL 7.32.0
- Apache 2.2.25
- PHP 5.5.4

Whenever I attempt to:

```
$ch = curl_init('www.google.com');
curl_exec($ch);

var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

within PHP, I get:

> Could not resolve host: www.google.com

If I change to `curl_init('80.233.168.207')` (resolved google.com), the script executes.

Though, running `curl www.google.com` in CLI, I get a `302 Moved` HTML page, due to redirect to localized site (*.lv), but still, that means that cURL executed successfully.

I have seen multiple similar questions (not on SE though), most of them saying that Apache is started either before or concurrently with Network Manager, hence not receiving DNS information. Most of the questions have answers explaining, that the issue can be temporarily resolved/debugged by explicitly stopping, then starting the Apache daemon (instead of restart/graceful-restart).

`fsockopen`, `file_get_contents` works flawlessly, though.

My Apache virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *.777>
    ServerAdmin stone@altas.lv
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot "/srv/stone/public"

    ErrorLog "/srv/stone/app/storage/logs/apache-errors.log"
    CustomLog "/srv/stone/app/storage/logs/apache-custom.log" common

    <Directory /srv/stone/public>
        php_admin_value open_basedir /

        # Pretty URL rewrites, better not to rely on .htaccess
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>

        # Prevent further overrides
        AllowOverride None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And global config just has a specific entry for `Listen 777`.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/163256/php-curl-fedora-issues-resolving-hostname-possibly-a-dns-problem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341644/curl-and-https-cannot-resolve-host), both lead to DNS problem, so, I think I may have problems with it too, plus, it clearly looks like it.

I've given a shot by changing virtual host entries to `0.0.0.0:777` and other configurations to no avail.

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: If you try to put `80.233.168.207 www.google.com` in your `/etc/hosts` you should be able to confirm that this is a DNS issue. It's a bit strange that your CLI command manage to perform the lookup though. FYI, the code works on my `Apache` installation.

Comment: Adding it to hosts did make the script work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem was with my `/etc/resolv.conf`.

I had set up a custom network connection manager, that executed an external command to set up nameservers from a specific configuration file. The setup would simply erase the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`, append with new info and then start the network interface, set it's parameters (IP, Mask, Cast, Gate) and voila.

Apparently that screwed up something. I guess I will have to look for different Before/After targets and write a custom `resolv.conf` updater.

I did leave `resolv.conf` static now, and that seems to fix the issue.

In the end, clearly this was a DNS problem. Thankfully, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 option?

```
$ch = curl_init('www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

And what is the output of the headers if you use the CURLOPT_HEADER option?

Comment: FYI: curl_setopt has to come before curl_exec, but, It doesn't even get that far to gather headers, it simply cannot connect. Dies all the time with `Could not resolve host`. I did already try the IPRESOLVE_V4 option before, doesn't work. Did it now again, nothing...

Comment: Oops, yes. That was a type. Had a working code here and it went wrong with copy and paste.

Comment: Why did you try `80.233.168.207`. This is not the same as your `www.google.com`. Here the `curl_info` gives `74.125.132.106` as `primary_ip` on `www.google.com`. could you try `curl_init('74.125.132.106')`? What result do you get? Here `80.233.168.207` goes right to google.com without giving a `page is moved`. Did you try `curl 80.233.168.207` and `curl 74.125.132.106` in CLI? (this may all be a localisation issue but you can try)

Comment: Haha, both with `curl -v 80.233.168.207` and `curl -v 74.125.132.106` in CLI i get a `200 OK`. With `curl www.google.com` i get a `302 Found`. Same with Curl in PHP. `ping www.google.com` gives me `74.125.132.147`.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that I have a problem with DNS'es related to Apache, mod_php and curl on the machine.

Comment: What does `print_r(gethostbynamel('www.google.com'));` show? Maybe Curl takes one of those (which can't resolve) while the CLI takes another. Do other sites work with curl? Or is it just the Google-ones?

Comment: `gethostbynamel` gives a bunch of `80.233.168.*` entries.

Comment: Maybe `curl_init(gethostbyname('www.google.com'));` works? Not that pretty though, and just hiding the root cause of the problem. :-)

Comment: Do other sites like `www.microsoft.com` also give this error?

Comment: And is giving `host www.google.com` on the CLI you the same numbers as `print_r(gethostbynamel('www.google.com'));`?